# inplace removal of quotes from list of list

Tags: python

I changed this list

```
orig_list=['"jason","hello1,hello2,hello3","somegroup2","bundle1","loc1"', '"ruby","hello","somegroup","bundle2","loc2"', '"sam","hello3,hello2","somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2","loc3"']

new_list=[x.split(",") for x in orig_list]


new_list=[['"jason"', '"hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3"', '"somegroup2"', '"bundle1"', '"loc1"'], ['"ruby"', '"hello"', '"somegroup"', '"bundle2"', '"loc2"'], ['"sam"', '"hello3', 'hello2"', '"somegroup3', 'somegroup4"', '"bundle2"', '"loc3"']]
```

what my intent is to get

```
[['jason', 'hello1,hello2,hello3', 'somegroup2', 'bundle1', 'loc1'], ['ruby', 'hello', 'somegroup', 'bundle2', 'loc2'], ['sam', 'hello3,hello2', 'somegroup3,somegroup4', 'bundle2', 'loc3']]
```

Is it possible to do it inplace and not creating a new one?

Update : I can have some elements in double quotes, all in double quotes, no double quotes and same in single quotes.

Comment: you need you write yourself an easy helper function

Comment: so I need read item by item and strip and copy to a new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an *in-place* removal of quotes, you need to add in the `[:]` to the list comprehension assignment:

```
orig_list = ['"jason","hello1,hello2,hello3","somegroup2","bundle1","loc1"', '"ruby","hello","somegroup","bundle2","loc2"', '"sam","hello3,hello2","somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2","loc3"']
id1 = id(orig_list)

orig_list[:] = [w for w in orig_list]
orig_list[:] = [g.replace('"', "'") for g in orig_list]
orig_list[:] = [h.split("',") for h in orig_list]
orig_list[:] = [[j.replace("'", '') for j in k] for k in orig_list]

id2 = id(orig_list)
print id1 == id2  # True
print orig_list  # [['jason', 'hello1,hello2,hello3', 'somegroup2', 'bundle1', 'loc1'], ['ruby', 'hello', 'somegroup', 'bundle2', 'loc2'], ['sam', 'hello3,hello2', 'somegroup3,somegroup4', 'bundle2', 'loc3']]
```

Note the `orig_list[:] = ...`. This ensures that you don't create a copy of the list (hence, making it not in-place).

Comment: wont work if I have double quotes on some elements, please see the update on the question. This is failing on some double quoted elements.

Comment: I've updated my code to work on your current "orig_list" input. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: it will fail on grouping if orig_list=['jason,"hello1,hello2,hello3",somegroup2,bundle1,loc1', 'ruby,hello,somegroup,bundle2,loc2', 'sam,'hello3,hello2',"somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2",loc3'] 
I am looking for a generic solution that can handle any type of quoting (double or single) as well as elements may or may not have quotes.

Comment: I misunderstood your original requirement. As per your previous comment, I've updated the code to work with the current orig_list.

Comment: If I use that input in the above comment, Python will not interpret it because it is invalid syntax with the quotes. If the quotes are backslashed so that it is a valid sequence of strings, like: ['jason,"hello1,hello2,hello3",somegroup2,bundle1,loc1', 'ruby,hello,somegroup,bundle2,loc2', 'sam,\'hello3,hello2\',"somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2",loc3'], it will work. Does that help?

Comment: but the problem is end user can upload a file with anytype of quotes and I want to handle it at my end. so end user wont escape anything..also they may forget to put quotes on some elements that why trying to handle that too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting on `,` split on `","`:

```
new_list=[[l.replace('"','') for l in x.split('","') for x in orig_list]
new_list
Out[99]: [['jason', 'hello1,hello2,hello3', 'somegroup2', 'bundle1', 'loc1'], ['ruby', 'hello', 'somegroup', 'bundle2', 'loc2'], ['sam', 'hello3,hello2', 'somegroup3,somegroup4', 'bundle2', 'loc3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Valid list, preserving grouping of grouped elements

Use the `reader` function from the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
from csv import reader

orig_list=['"jason","hello1,hello2,hello3","somegroup2","bundle1","loc1"', '"ruby","hello","somegroup","bundle2","loc2"', '"sam","hello3,hello2","somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2","loc3"']

new_list = []

for line in reader(orig_list):
  new_list.append(line)
```

This outputs the results you requested:

```
[['jason', 'hello1,hello2,hello3', 'somegroup2', 'bundle1', 'loc1'], ['ruby', 'hello', 'somegroup', 'bundle2', 'loc2'], ['sam', 'hello3,hello2', 'somegroup3,somegroup4', 'bundle2', 'loc3']]
```

## Ungroup all elements

If you want to ungroup all the comma-delimited elements, you can convert the list to a string and then split it:

```
orig_list2=['jason,"hello1,hello2,hello3",somegroup2,bundle1,loc1', 'ruby,hello,somegroup,bundle2,loc2', 'sam','hello3,hello2',"somegroup3,somegroup4","bundle2",'loc3']

orig_list2 = str(orig_list2)

# list of characters to remove
bad_chars = ['\'','"','[',']',' ']

for c in bad_chars:
  orig_list2 = orig_list2.replace(c,'')

# put into a list
new_list2 = orig_list2.split(',')
```

If you're dealing with a string that looks like a list but is invalid because some quotes are not complete pairs like the example you left in a comment for JohnZ, you can also use this method, but you wouldn't need to convert it to a string.

Comment: problem is i can have something like this as well:  ['jason,"hello2,helloe2","somegroup2",bundle1,loc1', 'ruby,hello,somegroup,bundle2,loc2', 'sam,hello3,somegroup3,bundle3,loc2'] and reader will merge hello2,helloe2,somegroup2 as one element. What I am trying to say is I can have quotes on some elements or no quotes or all quotes: quotes can be single quotes or double quotes. Getting messy to handle all of this.

Comment: So are you saying you want to return ALL comma-delimited strings as list elements? Because this will only group "hello2,helloe2". It will not group those with the rest of the string.